# How to make Signup/Login form working on AJAX secure?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, security

I have forms working with AJAX technology and would like to know which security issues could appear.

I know that all forms on site (with POST, PUT, DELETE methods) should have CSRF token. (Does it make sense for login or signup forms?)

And I'd like to provide you with some code (the simplest one) to make question larger:

```
    <form action="" method="" id="login-form">
         <input type="email" required="required" placeholder="example" id="username">
         <input type="password" required="required" placeholder="example" id="password">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#login-form').on('submit', function (e) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/someurl",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    username: $('#username').val(),
                    password: $('#password').val()
                }

            });

      });
    </script>
```

What else should I know to make any form (AJAX) secure?

Comment: You should be using SSL too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 
SSL - gotcha

Answer (score 1):

- If you really want to be sure your site and call to `/someurl` is secure, you should block HTTP and load all content over **HTTPS (no mixed content)**. A Strict-Transport-Security HTTP header can help you to avoid that your site is redirected first from HTTP to HTTPS.
- **CSRF** token is only needed if you store a session cookie that identifies and authenticates the user.
- Content security policy (**CSP**) header: you should protect your client side scripts against cross site scripting (XSS). If you don't, you don't know which scripts could be executed client side. Put your javascript in a separate file and mark this file in your CSP header as trusted.
- **injection** protection: you just pass user input to your service, so depending on your server code you could have a SQL injection vulnerability for example. You can protect your site in several ways, an example is escaping all user supplied input.

Comment: What place is better to store CSRF token?

Comment: The CSRF token should be stored server side in session and loaded in the html page as hidden input for example. An alternative for a session cookie is a (JWT) token that you store in local storage. But then you could have other security problems (no expiry date or cleanup) which you have to manage carefully.